# Possible to 'repeat' a dot command?

Tags: vim

I am deleting a vertical column of text, by doing `di"` and then `j.` or as many entries that I have, here is a recording with the keypresses shown: https://gyazo.com/4eb5007fe786581a9f78184697a2b3fe. Is there a way to repeat a `.` several times, for example, doing:

7j.

Similar to how I could do `7dd` ?

Comment: Dot-operator repeats last change, not a motion. I suggest you to read `:h repeating`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way:

```
6: ................. vim will put :.,+6
```

Then you type: `norm .` and the whole command will be

```
:.,.+6norm .<Enter>
```

If by any chance you have this pattern in non-contiguous lines you can run:

```
:g/pattern/norm .
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use `record` feature to do so. As follows:

- Press `qq` to start recording in `q` register
- `di"` : to delete in quotes(")
- `j` : to go one line down
- `q` : to stop recording
- `6@q` : to perform the recording in register `q` 6 more times (here you can replace 6 with any digit number